# moment().startOf('month').day() // => 0?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get the day number (1->7) of the first day of this month.

Today is Saturday (day 6) and the first day of April 2018 was Sunday (day 7)

`moment().day()` returns `6`: **CORRECT**

`moment().startOf('month').day()` returns `0`: **INCORRECT**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (from the docs)

> If the value given is from 0 to 6, the resulting date will be within
>   the current (Sunday-to-Saturday)